# Is light reflection or any other reflection a type of force?

Tags: forces, reflection, interactions

I have raised this question as during reflection the direction of the ray is changed. Force is created by the particles(bosons). so, are reflections a type of force?

Comment: Reflection is the name given to the phenomenon of the direction change. Are you asking whether a force is involved in the reflection of light?

Comment: When there is a dp/dt  the concept of force can be formulated

Comment: Force is a quantity with unit N. Reflection is a phenomenon and cannot be a force. A second point is that by including "any other reflection" your question is too broad. I think you want to know about optical reflection at a mirror. In this case it is better to be specific.

Answer (score 1):

Force is a change in momentum.

The momentum of incoming photons in a ray is in a different direction than of those outgoing an instant later in the reflection of that ray.  Therefore, you could say there's a force on the ray.  There's a reaction force on the mirror.  Light shining on a mirror pushes it away.

However, when one photon bounces off a mirror, it's technically a different photon going out than the one that went in.  In quantum mechanics, we consider the incoming photon to be destroyed, and the outgoing one to be created.  So it would sound odd  to say that a force acted upon the photon.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if a force is involved in the reflection of light from a smooth surface, then the broad answer is **yes.** Photons carry momentum proportional to the angular frequency of the light they compose: $p = \hbar \omega$. When a reflection occurs, part of the photons get a kick from the mirror and change their direction -- implying a force is involved. This is akin to any material object bouncing off a surface. For instance, if a light beam strikes a mirror at $45^{\circ}$ to the normal, each photon that gets reflected suffers a $\sqrt{2} \, \hbar \omega$ change in its momentum in magnitude. Note that I've assumed elastic scattering, where there is no loss of energy for the light.

Answer (score -1):

When a photon interacts with an atom, three things can happen:

1.elastic scattering, the photon keeps its energy and changes angle

2.inelastic scattering, the photon gives part of its energy to the atom and changes angle

3.absorption, the photon give all its energy to the absorbing atom (and electron)

Now in your case, reflection is 1., elastic scattering.

You are correct that the photons for example when they interact with a mirror's lattice's atoms, and get reflected (elastically scattered) they excerpt pressure on the mirror. So as you say they create force, by excerpting pressure on the mirror in the direction of incidence.

Now you are saying that reflections are types of forces, but in reality during a reflection, total energy is conserved. The photon changes direction and part of its momentum is transferred into the mirror's atoms' or molecules' kinetic energy and thus excerpting pressure on the mirror.

Reflection itself is not a force, but these forces are involved, and since this is an EM interaction between the atoms and the photons, the force mostly involved is the EM force (of course the other forces are involved too, but those effects should be negligible).

Comment: Probably the OP is talking about a mirror. In this case discussing atomic interaction is inadequate. The second paragraph is just confusing. "the force mostly involved is the EM force" Now you are a) using "force" in the sense of "interaction" not rate of change of momentum and b) photons represent em and other interaction do not play a role. There should be an incredibly small gravitational attraction be tween the mirror and the photon that is negligible and irrelevant to reflection